# HTML page not refreshing after rendering in views in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am currently working on a django project. Below is a function which handle "charts/" request

```
def charts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SecuritiesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = generateCharts(list(form.cleaned_data.get("securities_field")))
            return render(request, 'charts.html', {
                "tickerList": data["tickerList"],
                "current": data[data["tickerList"][1]]})

    if request.method == 'GET':
        ticker = request.GET.get('ticker', '')
        print(ticker)
        data = getData()
        print(data.keys())
        return render(request, 'charts.html', {
            "tickerList": data["tickerList"],
            "current": data[ticker]})

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': SecuritiesForm()})
```

as you can see when it is a GET request I update the dictionary and try to render the same HTML file. However my HTML page does not refresh and continues to show the same content, Can anyone help with this? It does not seem to refresh with the new data.

On HTML side I do this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <br>
    <div class="buttonRow">
        {% for t in tickerList %}
            <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="changeChart(this.value)" value="{{ t }}">{{ t }}</button>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
    <br><br>
    {% if current %}
        {{ current | safe }}
    {% else %}
        <p>NO Graph</p>
    {% endif %}

    <script>
        function changeChart(ticker) {
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url = "?ticker=" + ticker;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
        }

    </script>

    <style>
        .buttonRow {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How should your page refresh? How do you initialize a refresh with an updated ticker?

Comment: basically it should show the new content right? I changed the dictionary as you can see and render again. Would you like me to include my HTML code too?
I dont completely understand your question. I expect that when I render after getting a GET request , the HTML page should show the new value associated with "current" key

Comment: I can see that, but somewhere in the frontend there should be a new request to get a refresh right? Maybe include the relevant template too.

Comment: Hi , I have included the relevant template too

Comment: You can not refresh a page using the XMLHttpRequest, I think you might find what you need here: https://betterprogramming.pub/redirect-refresh-and-access-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-javascript-3d9160e8317e

Comment: Even when I refresh manually it doesnt seem to show the updated content

Comment: You need to update the url parameter `ticker` too?

Comment: When the button is clicked its value is sent to the JavaScript function changeChart which triggers the GET request using the value (ticker) as URL parameter

Comment: Is `data` actually getting updated the way you believe it is?

Comment: You might also finish your POST process with a redirection (back to the same page), which is the convention. If this makes things work, something was being cached that you didn't want cached.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Ajax Query to call the view instead of same html page first, I am too stuck at the same point but with the above implementation when I refresh the page refreshed data is rendered.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33455716)